# API is not working in flutter_web(Enabled CORS)

Tags: django, flutter

I Made one POST API in Django rest framework. It working perfectly in Postman in also chrome and other browsers but it is not working in my flutter_web project. it is giving me XMLHttpRequest error. for enable CORS I had used python -m pip install django-cors-headers.

you can check my api from https://findweight.herokuapp.com/idealweight which takes raw data for example 5.

you can check my whole error from following image:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx8Xp.png

Comment: Please share the **exact** and **full** error. You likely still did not properly enable CORS for your API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have applied all the migrations properly on the backend.
If not then migrate it first by `python manage.py migrate`.

And restart your server again and see the logs by changing `DEBUG = True`,
So you can see what is the error (**NOTE**: Make sure you change `DEBUG = False` before going to production).

And also, check if you have set up CORS property properly on the backend.